# Static Variable issue in python when converting Binary tree to doubly linked list

Tags: python, binary-tree, static-members, doubly-linked-list

I have already implemented this algorithm in C++. But I started learning python and so I was trying to implement it in python. But since there is no concept of static variable in python, I am unable to complete it successfully.

In method "convert_to_doubly_ll", I am unable to decide how to simulate static variable "prev".

I checked many ways of simulating static variable in python like:
1. declaring variable as global variable
2. attaching variable to method of class
3. defining variable as class variable
4. making the function as generator function
and some more... but I am unable to apply any in this scenario.

The code that I wrote is as follows:

```
import sys

class Tree: 
    def __init__(self, v, l=None, r=None):
        self.v = v
        self.l = l
        self.r = r

    def convert_to_doubly_ll(self, head=None):  
        static prev = None    # it does not work

        if self.l is not None:
            self.l.convert_to_doubly_ll(head)

        if prev is None:
            head = self     
        self.l = prev
        if prev is not None:
            prev.r = self
        prev = self

        if self.r is not None:
            self.r.convert_to_doubly_ll(head)

        return head

    def print_doubly_ll(self):
        print self.v
        if self.r is not None:
            self.r.print_doubly_ll()
```

The driver program:

```
a = Tree(1)
b = Tree(4)
c = Tree(6)
d = Tree(8)
e = Tree(2, a)
f = Tree(3, e, b)
g = Tree(7, c, d)
h = Tree(5, f, g)

head = h.convert_to_doubly_ll()
head.print_doubly_ll()
```

Comment: Please paste a full traceback.  The issue isn't in the method you indicate, because that method never accesses a `.v` property of any object.

Comment: everything is passed by reference in python ... except for immutable objects ... since they are immutable ...

Comment: The only piece in this code that references `v` is in `print_doubly_ll` method, and only if you manage to pass `None` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some effort, I figured out how to write this algo without static variable and in pythonic way (using generators). My code is as follows:

```
import sys

class Tree: 
    def __init__(self, v, l=None, r=None):
        self.v = v
        self.l = l
        self.r = r

    def get_inorder_tree(self):  
        if not self:
            return

        if self.l:
            for node in self.l.get_inorder_tree():
                yield node
        yield self
        if self.r:  
            for node in self.r.get_inorder_tree():
                yield node

    def convert_to_doubly_ll(self):
        prev = None

        for node in self.get_inorder_tree():
            node.l = prev
            if prev is None:
                head = node
            else:
                prev.r = node
            prev = node
        return head

    def print_doubly_ll(self):
        print self.v
        if self.r is not None:
            self.r.print_doubly_ll()


def main():
    a = Tree(1)
    b = Tree(4)
    c = Tree(6)
    d = Tree(8)
    e = Tree(2, a)
    f = Tree(3, e, b)
    g = Tree(7, c, d)
    h = Tree(5, f, g)

    head = h.convert_to_doubly_ll()
    head.print_doubly_ll()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The values of `head` and `tail` do not change from `None` in `convert_to_doubly_ll` since `convert_to_doubly_ll_util` does not return their updated values. You could rewrite your code:

```
class Tree: 
    def __init__(self, v, l=None, r=None):
        self.v = v
        self.l = l
        self.r = r

    def convert_to_doubly_ll_util(self, head, tail):
        if self.l is not None:
            self.l.convert_to_doubly_ll_util(head, tail)

        self.l = tail
        if tail is not None:
            tail.r = self
        tail = self
        if head is None:
            head = tail

        if self.r is not None:
            self.r.convert_to_doubly_ll_util(head, tail)
        return head, tail


    def convert_to_doubly_ll(self):
        head = None
        tail = None
        head, tail = self.convert_to_doubly_ll_util(head, tail)
        return head, tail

    def print_doubly_ll(self):
        print self.v
        if self.r is not None:
            self.r.print_doubly_ll()
```